# Mysql to Mongodb data migration application for use in production environment

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a mysql database that receives data every 10 seconds and its a lot of data i receive.I am looking for an application that can transfer my database from mysql to mongodb. I am looking for a proven solution that works in production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends from what Your need, it could be replication, such as:

- https://pubs.vmware.com/continuent/tungsten-replicator-3.0/deployment-mongodb.html
- http://www.symmetricds.org  -

or ETL Tools, like:

- Telend
- Pentaho
- Informatica